# How to fix "name error '_' not defined in powershell terminal while trying to run a python script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, discord

I'm trying to make a bot for discord and am running into problems getting it to run. I have no experience in coding.
I copied the scripts into visual studio for a test to see if I can get it to work, and I think I copied it right. I just don't know what I'm doing wrong when trying to run it in the terminal.

[image: pic of my visual studio]

Comment: type `python Donnie.py` in the terminal, read a good book of Python for beginners

Comment: don't open the User Home directory as a workspace in VSC and put your code there, create a sub dir and open that as a workspace/folder, if you go to use source control that will be so much easier

Comment: why can't I see your error `name error '_'....` in the image

Comment: why do post a capture of your complete desktop, including the weather forecast, when only the Powershell part is of interest, and that is text you could copy/paste, a lot easier then making a screenshot  and adding that to the post

Answer (score 0):

You have to type `python Donnie.py` in the terminal and hit enter.

Welcome to programming :)

Comment: if the same info is already mentioned in a comment by somebody this answer is: reputation harvesting

Answer (score 0):

The vscode terminal uses the power shell built into Windows.

If you type `python` in the terminal and press enter, the python executable will be executed and the python interactive window will open.

Here, you can directly type python language and run, such as `print("hello")`.

[image]

If what you want to run is a python script file. Then you should use the play button at the top right of the interface and select **Run Python File**.

[image]

If you want to run with the command, use `python youfilename.py` command in the terminal to run the entire script file.

[image]